# Функция возвращает неправильное значение при использовании zope.interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, zope.interface

Доброго времени суток.

Есть класс Concatination, который принимает 2 буквы(а именно 2 объекта Letter) и возвращает строку из двух букв.

```
import zope.interface

class IExpression(zope.interface.Interface):
    def evaluate(self):
        """ Retrns the value of the expression """


class Concatination(IExpression):
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def evaluate(self):
        return self.left.evaluate() + self.right.evaluate()


class Letter:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l;

    def evaluate(self):
        return self.l
```

Однако, в коде:

```
c = Concatination(Letter('a'),Letter('b'))
print(c.evaluate())
```

выдает значение последней буквы, а именно b.

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку.

Comment: Zope у меня не захотел устанавливаться, но если не использовать его, то код полностью рабочий и выводит именно `ab`

Comment: @andreymal , в чем у вас проблема возникла в установке? спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: @andreymal могу воспроизвести ошибку (возвращается только `'b'`). Если убрать наследование от IExpression, то 'ab' возвращается. `pip install zope.interface` работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы указать, что класс реализует интерфейс, следует [@implementer](https://zopeinterface.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.ru.html#id6) использовать вместо наследования:

```
@zope.interface.implementer(IExpression)
class Concatination:
    ...
```

Также при объявлении метода в интерфейсе, `self` не следует использовать. [Интерфейс документирует как метод следует использовать](https://zopeinterface.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.ru.html#id2):

```
class IExpression(zope.interface.Interface):
    def evaluate():
        """Return the value of the expression."""
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!